# compare Set<Long> that contains integers to Set<Long>

Tags: java

I have a controller that returns a `Set<Long>` in its response`s body :

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getIds(){
    Set<Long> ids =  someFunc(..);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(ids);
}
```

In my test I'm trying to compare the result of the rest call to a different `Set<Long>`

```
MockHttpServletResponse result = mockMvc.perform(.....).andReturn().getResponse();
Set<Long> responseBody  = objectMapper.readValue(result.getContentAsByteArray(), Set.class);
responseBody = responseBody.stream().map(number->number.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
assertThat(responseBody.equals(otherSet),is(true));
```

When I run the code in debug mode I saw that the responseBody contains Integer objects.

The error that I'm getting on the line with the mapping (`map(number->number.longValue())`) :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

It seems that the object mapper convert the Long objects (ids) to Integer objects because it can fit into an integer..

I know that I can use :

`new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS,true);`

but I want to find a solution that will convert the value and not add a constraint on my mapper.

Comment: "It seems that the object mapper convert the Long object to Integer because it can fit into an integer.." I highly highly doubt it. Much more likely that you actually have added an Integer into your Set<Long> (can absolutely happen), so that when you try to map, you are getting a ClassCastException.

Comment: Before returning the Set<Long> I checked and the objects are Long type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your data as `Set<Long>`. Use `TypeReference` to specify the type you want to read, then you don't need to convert `Integer` into `Long`

```
Set<Long> responseBody  = objectMapper.readValue(result.getContentAsByteArray(),
                                                      new TypeReference<Set<Long>>(){});
```